# NestJS get exsiting instance of service when using useFacetory()

Tags: angular, typescript, nestjs

I have a service class `ServiceB` which injecting `ServiceA`

```js
export class ServiceB {
  constructor(
    @Inject(ServiceA)
    private readonly serviceA: ServiceA,
  ) {}
```

ServiceA is in ModuleA

```js
@Module({
  providers: [ServiceA],
  exports: [ServiceA],
})
export class ModuleA {}
```

And I combine all of them in AppModule

```js
@Module({
  imports: [ModuleA],
  providers: [ServiceB]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

### THE QUESTION IS

I want to add a parameter in ServiceB's constructor

```js
export class ServiceB {
  constructor(
    @Inject(ServiceA)
    private readonly serviceA: ServiceA,
    name: string
  ) {}
```

and I try to use `useFactory()` in AppModule to add that parameter

```js
@Module({
  imports: [ModeulA],
  providers: [
  {
    provide: ServiceB,
    useFactory: () => new ServiceB(
      new ServiceA(),
      'JOHN'
    )
  }
  ]
})
export class AppModule{}
```

This cause generting a sencond ServiceA instance. How can I find the exsiting ServiceA instance and inject into ServiceB?

Comment: what about [`useExisting`](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#alias-providers-useexisting)?

Comment: Not sure if I understand `useExisting` correctly. But I still need to `new ServiceB()` somewhere then set it to useExisting, and still need to `new ServiceA()` again

Answer (score 1):

Read the docs [Factory providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#factory-providers-usefactory)

Add ServiceA class to `inject` property and your factory function will receive the instance once called.

```
    {
    provide: ServiceB,
    useFactory: (srvA: ServiceA) => new ServiceB(
      srvA,
      'JOHN'
    ),
    inject: [ServiceA]
    }
```